# php - how to make sure that the uploaded file is a jpg, gif or png?

Tags: php, gd

In php I can check if a uploaded file has proper type by extension, so code should look like this:

```
if ((($_FILES["photo1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["photo1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["photo1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["photo1"]["size"] < 500000)) //also limiting size
```

Then in next step in my code I prepare a file for further processing. But what if someone changes a text_file.doc or javascript_file.js to samplefile.jpg before upload?

```
move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name']), "photos/1.jpg");
$source1 = imagecreatefromjpeg("../photos/source1.jpg");
```

Then user will see errors from `imagecreatefromjpeg` step:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg: JPEG
library reports unrecoverable error: in...
```

How to skip a processing part if a file is not a graphic file and not display errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and check for possible errors, something like this:

```
try {
    $size = getimagesize("your_image_file");
    echo 'image!';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'no known image format!'; 
}
```

This GD function is not perfect, but it can cope with several image file formats.

There are several ways to omit the warnings in PHP. If an error like this can happen, it usually will happen. Either expect it in your code (usually preferrable, see my example with try...catch) or configurate your enviroment to your needs (p.e. omit warnings).

Comment: I don't think this will work correctly.  If somebody renames a PNG file to give it a JPG extension, `getimagesize` could still return a correct size, however `imagecreatefromjpeg` function would error, as the underline stream is not a JPEG.

Comment: The poster asks _How to skip a processing part if a file is not a graphic file_, and not how to verify if the JPG is really a JPG. Since he expects other formats too, he'll have to use more inventive ways to seperately process them later on anyway.

Comment: After your code should I put lines `if $size!=0 { //image processing }` ?

Comment: Something like this. Keep in mind at that stage you "only" have determined the uploaded file just is an image - not, what kind of image it is (maybe `exif-imagetype`, http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php, is better suited for that task). `imagecreatefromjpeg` is best suited for... well, jpegs.

Comment: getimagesize() returns the exact file and mime types anyways, so it's trivial to check `if (filename has .jpg) && (detected mime type = image/jpeg) { ... } else { hey something goofy here! }`

Comment: Ah yes, even better then for my first choice how to check it!

Answer (score 5):

As written on the documentation for [file-uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), it is stated that`$_FILES['userfile']['type']` is

> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

This means it is not checked on the php side, which you should do with [mime_content_type](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)  and confirm its mime type.

Alternatively, you could use [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/getimagesize) to actually check if the file that has been uploaded has a imagesize, and if not, then its not an image.

Comment: That's not correct! As you said it's based on what the browser says, but that isn't always correct (you could just send application/word+doc - or whatever). So you CAN rename anything to some other name and provide a false mime-type to make PHP believe anything.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should edit php.ini to disable the output of warnings and error messages to the user, so these users don't see the error. At least for production systems this is recommended.

Then, you should be able to check the return value of the function. According to http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php, it is supposed to return false if it cannot open the file you supplied.

Additionally, with exception handling ( see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php ), you can catch and process error messages and warnings like the one you posted above.